# Line integral on unit circle over non-holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

In my lecture notes on complex analysis, there are a few "challenges" whether or not you can find a continuous function $f$ on the disc $D(0,1)$ for which

$ \int_{\partial D(0,r)}f(\zeta)d\zeta = 0$

My idea was to use $|z|^2$, since this equals $z \bar{z}$ and I can solve the integral in the following way:

$ \int_{\partial D(0,r)}z \bar{z}dz = \int\int_{D(0,r)}z d\bar{z}dz = \int\int_{D(0,r)}r(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}) (2irdrd\theta) = 2i \cdot \int_0^{2\pi}(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})d\theta \cdot \int_0^rr^2dr$

The integral over $\theta$ then gives 0 and thus we have found that $|z|^2$ is a suitable function. However, I'm not sure if this is actually correct and whether or not I am allowed to make the very first step ($\bar{z} = \int 1 d\bar{z}$).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double integration is no needed. Using polar coordinates $z=re^{i\theta},$
$$\int\limits_{\partial D(0,r)}z \bar{z}dz =r^2 \int\limits_{\partial D(0,r)}dz=r^2 \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}d(re^{i\theta})=r^3 {e^{i\theta}}\left|_{0}^{2\pi}\right.=0.$$